# How to access a Button's titleLabel from inside it's action in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, action

Very simply, if I am declaring a button like:

```
Button("buttonLabel") {
    //How do I access the titleLabel.text, in this case "buttonLabel" inside the button's action?
}
```

Side Note: If I can add anything to contextualize this, I can, but I feel like there must be some super simple way to access the label...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access it by declaring it as a variable outside body as a member of the `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let buttonLabel = "buttonLabel"

    var body: some View {
        Button(buttonLabel) {
            print("Pressed \(self.buttonLabel)")
        }
    }
}
```

If your requirement is to check/modify the button text then here is an example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonLabel = "Tap me!"

    var body: some View {
        Button(buttonLabel) {
            self.buttonLabel = self.buttonLabel == "Tap me!" ? "I was tapped!" : "Tap me!"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the value of the label, you can set it as a property in your view. If you want to be able to modify it from within your action, you'll need to mark it with a `@State` wrapper, as shown below.

```
struct YourView: View {
    @State var label = "Tap Me"

    var body: some View {
        Button(label) {
            self.label = "Tapped!"
        }
    }
}
```